# Plotting on left and right axis using matplotlib 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new using Matplotlib and I got some questions.

This is the first Case:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra1no.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQSrq.png

Is there any way to change the Label shown on the axis when changing the azimuth 90 degrees? What I want is that instead of having the same label on the other side, I'd like to to be West.

My other question is that if there's a way to prevent the graph from going to a negative elevation?

[3] https://i.stack.imgur.com/B493F.png

Here's the code

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
points = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],
                  [1, -1, -1 ],
                  [1, 1, -1],
                  [-1, 1, -1],
                  [-1, -1, 1],
                  [1, -1, 1 ],
                  [1, 1, 1],
                  [-1, 1, 1]])
Z = points
Z = 10.0*Z
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

r = [-1,1]
X, Y = np.meshgrid(r, r)
ax.scatter3D(Z[:, 0], Z[:, 1], Z[:, 2])
verts = [[Z[0],Z[1],Z[2],Z[3]],
 [Z[4],Z[5],Z[6],Z[7]],
 [Z[0],Z[1],Z[5],Z[4]],
 [Z[2],Z[3],Z[7],Z[6]],
 [Z[1],Z[2],Z[6],Z[5]],
 [Z[4],Z[7],Z[3],Z[0]]]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts, facecolors='cyan', linewidths=1, edgecolors='r', alpha=.20))
ax.set_xlabel('South', fontweight ='bold')
ax.set_ylabel('East')
#ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use [event handling](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/event_handling.html) to do this.

For your first question (setting the "East" or "West" label), we can catch when there has been a [draw event](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.DrawEvent) and define our `ylabel` accordingly.

For the second question (stopping the elevation going negative), we could make sure the elevation is limited to only positive numbers.

An example function would look like this. Add this just before `plt.show()` in your script:

```
def draw_func(event):
    # Change label to East or West depending on azimuth
    if ax.azim > 90 or ax.azim < -90:
        ax.set_ylabel('West')
    else:
        ax.set_ylabel('East')

    # don't let elevation go negative
    if ax.elev < 1:
        ax.view_init(elev=max(ax.elev, 1), azim=ax.azim)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', draw_func)
```

[image]

The only issue I see with this solution is it allows the view elevation to go negative and the snaps back to positive. This may be sufficient for you; if not, someone else might know a better solution